# how to store vector in a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store some int vectors into a vector, so firstly I initialize a vector type vector, then iterate for begin to end, and store int numbers into each subvectoer from 0 to 4 like below code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>  > v(12);

void fun_1(std::vector<int> a )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        a.push_back(i);
    }
}
int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        fun_1(v[i]);
    }

    cout<<v[0].at(2);
}
```

So after I done that, there is always a segmentation fault which I think is because subvector is still empty, they are not assigned, so I am wondering how can I modify this to reach my goal? Thank for any idea.

Comment: Just like you did. Put the `cout` inside of the function.

Comment: You need to pass the vector to the function by reference.

Comment: @latedeveloper thank you! problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function fun_1 accepts its input parameter by copy so it only modifies *the local copy* of the vector, not the original one passed in.
So the original one remains empty. Once you attempt to access one of its (non-existent) elements, it throws an exception.

If you change fun_1 to accept its argument by reference:

```
void fun_1(std::vector<int>& a )
```

This should work just fine.

Comment: thank you so much! problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You send parameter to your function by copy , you should send this by 
reference:

```
void fun_1(std::vector<int> &a )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        a.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently passing the vector by value in fun_1, so once you return, all of the changes you made to a are discarded. fun_1 should look something like

```
void fun_1(std::vector<int> &a )
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   {
      a.push_back(i);
   }
}
```

This will cause the call to fun_1 in main to actually manipulate v, instead of manipulating a copy of v.

Comment: Looks like @Morteza beat me to it.